# Reset modal contents after open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Verwijderen</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ route('admin_customers_single', $customer->id) }}">{{ $customer->name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $customer->email }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('admin_customers_delete', $customer->id) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i click on the anchor, a model opens with the data.

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $('#nameInput').val(data.name);
                $('#genderInput').val(data.gender);
                $('#addressInput').val(data.address);
                $('#zipCodeInput').val(data.zip_code);
                $('#cityInput').val(data.city);
                $('#countryInput').val(data.country_id);
                $('#languageInput').val(data.language);
                $('#emailInput').val(data.input);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

The data displays, so it works.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" role="button">@lang('admin.customers_new')</a>
```

After clicking on this anchor, there is still data..
How do i reset the modal to its default content?

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `hidden.bs.modal` event.

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the
>   user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Reset the fields values here.
})
```

[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)